# Gitlab pages won’t update site even though the pipeline is successful

Tags: reactjs, nginx, gitlab

So I have deployed my react website into our server using nginx but whenever I pushed my code into the main repository, the website in my domain is not updating. I checked the file directly into the server and it is being updated but whenever I visit the website, it is not changing

I tried checking my build file directly into the server and it is being updated but whenever I visit the website, it is not changing

Comment: This sounds like it could be related to some caching happening somewhere along the line. 

The first thing to check is if it is your web browser caching the old page. 

You can typically force a refresh in most browsers by holding down ctrl + F5. On a Mac that is likely command + shift + R.

Alternatively, you can also turn off caching by using the developer console. Google is your friend. 

Other, less likely things could be a CDN or Proxy, but see how you go with force refresh.


Sorry, if I'm pointing out the obvious but could it be as simple as the browser caching the old site?